# How to find duplicates pairs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a MySQL table like this:

> |  id1  |  id2  |
>
> | 34567 | 75879 | <---- pair1
>
> | 13245 | 46753 |
>
> | 75879 | 34567 | <---- pair2
>
> | 06898 | 00013 |

with 37 000 entries.

What is the SQL Request or how can i identify duplicates pairs (like pair1 and pair2)?

Thanks

Comment: See this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590010/delete-duplicate-records-without-creating-a-temporary-table

Answer (score 3):

if you want to identify the duplicates and count them at the same time, you could use:

```
SELECT if(id1 < id2, id1, id2), if (id1 < id2, id2, id1), count(*)
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

This does not perform a join, which might be faster in the end.

Comment: It would be very interested to see the running time on your query against a JOIN, especially against a large table.+1 for the underdog query !!!

Comment: I say underdog because most would probably scoff a query not using a JOIN, but I like queries that come from thinking outside the box.

Answer (score 2):

If you join the table with it self you can filter out the ones you need.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM your_table yt1,
       your_table yt2 
 WHERE (yt1.id1 = yt2.id2 AND yt1.id2 = yt1.id1)
    OR (yt1.id1 = yt2.id1 AND yt1.id2 = yt2.id2)
```

Comment: small update to your answer, I think better should add **`OR (yt1.id1 = yt2.id1 AND yt1.id2 = yt2.id2)`**

Comment: You're right, I'll add it. It's not in the question but likely it should be added anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The original post is 1000 years old, but here's another form:

```
SELECT CONCAT(d1, '/' d2) AS pair, count(*) AS total
FROM your_table
GROUP BY pair HAVING total > 1
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

May or may not perform as well as the other suggested answers.

Comment: fyi missing comma in concat() args.  Should be `CONCAT(d1, '/', d2)`