# delete duplicate entry in mysql without temporary tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have deleted duplicate rows in a mysql table using temporary tables. Is it possible to do it without using it? I have searched a lot but did not find any solution.

```
number | status | service
1234 | A | x1
1234 | D | x1
1234 | D | x1
1234 | A | x2
1234 | D | x2
2345 | A | x1
```

My basic need is that there should be only one row which is instatus d for a perticular number and service. there are a lot of entries in the table

Comment: It depends. You have to be much more specific and provide table schema , sample data, desired outcome

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete duplicate records without creating a temporary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590010/delete-duplicate-records-without-creating-a-temporary-table)

Comment: @PreetSangha: NO that solution dosnt suite my requirement.

Comment: @peterm: i have editted the question . my requirement is that duplicate entries with status 'D' should be deleted.

Comment: Are these all columns in your table? Do you have any id column?

Comment: @peterm: There is one more column which is serial number and is auto incremented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to let MySql do the job applying a `UNIQUE` constraint with `IGNORE` option (which will treat errors as warnings) effectively de-duplicating the table

```sql
ALTER TABLE Table1 ENGINE MyISAM; -- this obviously needed only if your ENGINE is not MyISAM
ALTER IGNORE TABLE Table1 ADD UNIQUE (`number`, `status`, `service`);
ALTER TABLE Table1 ENGINE InnoDB; -- again this is only needed if your ENGINE was other than MyISAM
```

After that you'll get:

```
| NUMBER | STATUS | SERVICE |
-----------------------------
|   1234 |      A |      x1 |
|   1234 |      A |      x2 |
|   1234 |      D |      x1 |
|   1234 |      D |      x2 |
|   2345 |      A |      x1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db094/1)** demo

---

Since *...There is one more column which is serial number and is auto incremented...*
another option is to use a query like this

```sql
DELETE t
  FROM Table1 t JOIN
(
SELECT number, status, service, MAX(serial) serial
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY number, status, service
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) q ON t.number = q.number
   AND t.status = q.status
   AND t.service = q.service
   AND t.serial <> q.serial
```

Outcome is the same:

```
| SERIAL | NUMBER | STATUS | SERVICE |
--------------------------------------
|      1 |   1234 |      A |      x1 |
|      4 |   1234 |      A |      x2 |
|      3 |   1234 |      D |      x1 |
|      5 |   1234 |      D |      x2 |
|      6 |   2345 |      A |      x1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49aaa/2)** demo

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:-

```
DELETE t1 FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE t1.name = t2.name AND t1.id > t2.id;
```

provided name and id are the columns in table

Checkout this [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/01/22/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql-without-using-temporary-table/)

Comment: i can not use operators as it is a character which is a duplicate.