# Is it possible to delete perfect duplicate records from mysql, without creating a temporary table

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to delete perfect duplicate records from mysql, without creating a temporary table in a single query????

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`fruit`, `price`) VALUES
('apple', 10),
('grape', 50),
('apple', 10),
('orange', 100),
('orange', 100),
('orange', 100),
('pinaple', 200),
('pinaple', 200),
('pinaple', 200),
('pinaple', 200);
```

and the result should be

```
"apple","10"
"orange","100"
"pinaple","200"
"grape","50"
```

in a single query

> Description:
>
> If there is any uniquely identifiable fields then remove the duplicates like this [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)
>
> If the there is only one particular item then can be able to remove the duplicates by using limit of delete query
>
> DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name`='value' LIMIT 1;
>
> Multi line solution
>   [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590010/delete-duplicate-records-without-creating-a-temporary-table)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a unique index to the table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD CONSTRAINT unique_fruits UNIQUE (fruit, price)
```

This should remove duplicates in a single statement without a temporary table.  If you don't want the unique constraint moving forward, then you can remove it:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP INDEX unique_fruits
```